# How to create Axis Web Service Client for a local WSDL file?

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans, wsdl, axis

i have local WSDL file. i tried to create JAX-WS Web service client which is available by default in Netbeans. But there are problems in accessing the service. So i tried to create Axis Web Service client by installing the plugin.

But i don't find any way to import the WSDL and access the services available like JAX- WS Style.

I have looked at Create Axis Service from WSDL option but when i import the WSDL i don't find any method available

How can i import and access the WSDL in Netbeans using Axis?

**EDIT:**

The problem is not in accessing, i was successful in invoking the services but in few services i wasn't able to find one method that is part of the service. However when i tried the same in C# environment i was able to find all the method. So that's the reason i was moving to Axis

Comment: If there are "problems" in accessing the service, I'm not sure using another web services stack will solve them. Maybe you should update your question to describe those problems.

Comment: Maybe a problem with the WSDL then, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try creating the service through [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/). Moreover if you are in an early phase of deciding which web service framework to use, you can also consider [CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/) instead of Axis.

**EDIT:** In soapUI from the tools menu you can create artifacts for JAX-WS, Axis, CXF etc.

Comment: soapUI seems to be a testing tool. How can i use it to invoke web service and program in Java?

Comment: i am really new and i don't know to use it. Can you please point me to any tutorial please

Comment: You can start from http://www.soapui.org/gettingstarted/index.html soapUI is fairly easy to learn and use.

Answer (score 0):

I Agree with Pascal comment here, moving to another stack might not solve your problems.
Also I suggest not creating the web service client with Netbeans wizard but using the jax-ws wsimport commands (part of any java SDK).
You can use this ant task:

```
<target name="wsimport" depends="" description="create client code">
    <exec executable="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_16\bin\wsimport">
        <arg line="-d ${basedir}/bin -keep -p com.ttt.client.ws -s ${basedir}/src  wsdl/wsdlfile.wsdl -b wsdl/wsdlfile.xsd"/>
    </exec> 
</target>
```

Or just run the command from a shell/cmd.

Comment: May i know why your suggesting me not to use Netbeans wizard? it seems pretty easier to create in netbeans

Comment: I used it long time ago and it didn't work for me.
Ended up with this kind of ant script (which is quite simple to implement/run).